# Ubuntu 18.04 show date and time on every screen

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-gnome, date, top-bar

Since the update to 18.04 from 16.04, i see top bar with date and time only on the primary screen of my notebook. On the other screens the top bar is not shown.

Another anoying thing is i see only the actual weekday and time of the day. I would like to see the whole date with time without clicking on it...

I've searched along by google but i didnt found a solution...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Install GNOME Tweak Tool:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Go to Top Bar on the left and enable **date** under **clock**.

Comment: Thank you, it works for me. But can i make the top bar on every screen visible? Actual its only on the primary screen.

Comment: Why the upvotes? This answer does not answer the question in the title: "Ubuntu 18.04 show date and time **on every screen**". Anyone have an aswer to this?

Comment: Go to Top Bar on the left and enable date under clock.

I did not getting this or not found on ubuntu 18.4

Comment: This answer does not address the question, which is showing this on EVERY monitor.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22, I get an error ```Package 'gnome-tweak-tool' has no installation candidate```.

Answer (score 14):

You can change setting from terminal too using following command.

`$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date true`

Comment: This worked for me to add the date to the time on my top bar.  Mine was only showing the time and not the date at all.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Installing "Multi Monitors Add-On" showed topbar on both my displays.

Software Center, search "Multi Monitors Add-On", Install.

Its option "Show Panel on additional monitors" is turned on by default.

Comment: This is working, but I am able to see only the time and activities button in the second monitor's top bar. How can I have the other icons like battery, sound, wifi, etc on the second monitor as well?