# Ubuntu 20.04 show date/time/volume on every screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, top-bar

Since the update to 20.04 from 16.04, I see top bar with date and time and volume control --- but only on the primary screen of my computer. On the other screens, the top bar is not shown.

I've searched with duckgo and google but didn't find a solution.

This was [asked before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036034/ubuntu-18-04-show-date-and-time-on-every-screen), but without an answer.

To be clear, I'm looking for something in a package manager or official channel, and not a custom script I can sideload.

Comment: Have you tried this extension? https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/

Comment: I looked for it in the Software Center but it was absent.

Comment: Dont you want to download it n install??

Comment: No, I want something through the official package management systems that can also offer updates if needed.  This is a pretty basic function of an operating system that should be supported.

Comment: Why not use Unity in 20.04 like you used in 16.04?

Comment: I considered it, but I wanted to use Gnome since it's the new default.  You're talking about going to straight to the nuke option because there's a pebble in the street LOL

Answer (score 8):

For a solution based on an official package: make sure that you have "Universe" enabled in your repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

and that you're using the GNOME desktop or a derivative.

Search Synaptic (or via apt) for the package:

> gnome-shell-extension-multi-monitors

Install it, along with the GNOME tweak tool (package "gnome-tweaks", not "gnome-tweak-tool" - the latter is to access some additional settings):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-multi-monitors gnome-tweaks
```

You’ll have to log out and back in (sometimes just reboot your system). After that, search for the Tweak Tool in GNOME menu and launch it. Select "Extensions" on the left-hand side, and scroll till you see multi-monitors-add-on. Activate the slider.

You should see a dual monitor symbol on your taskbar. Click it and select "Preferences". This prefs page will let you tweak all sorts of options... including "Show panel on additional monitors", which is the setting that you are looking for.

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository universe` to enable "Universe" in the repositories

Comment: This seems like it could be the correct answer, except it's not working.  https://i.imgur.com/As4aQfU.png  There is no multimonitor extension there despite completing these steps successfully.

Comment: @b264: Wait, that's the wrong extensions list. I have edited my answer! So sorry. You want gnome-tweaks package, not gnome-tweak-tool! See https://imgur.com/a/yJiLyEE.

Comment: This is so close to the correct answer!  Unfortunately, it just doesn't work :sob: because "error loading extension" https://imgur.com/jLqy9ug https://pastebin.com/RJV3spmh

Comment: It appears those 3 lines of code are not in the main branch on github https://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on/blob/master/multi-monitors-add-on%40spin83/mmpanel.js#L384

Comment: Curiously, the code throwing the error is not in the main branch of the extension.  Maybe the package manger copy is out of date? https://pastebin.com/yv4FVbqj https://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on/blob/master/multi-monitors-add-on%40spin83/mmpanel.js#L384  the offending lines were removed in this commit: https://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on/commit/15a0d3ceea6a601d4c4b709a0fd655ff7d6d27ea#diff-a90eb6aeed84b64a03b86f59cbf3d134dd1037ed6f29bdb6eb389530f32dd435

Comment: Ah, the official packages is behind... so you are stuck with installation from github, unless you can wait. Effectively then, this is the right answer, but unfortunately the official package has a bug... perhaps log it?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-multi-monitors/+bug/1922318

Comment: This is working, but I am able to see only the time and activities button in the second monitor's top bar. How can I have the other icons like battery, sound, wifi on the second monitor as well?

Comment: @spharish: you can just right-click the new toolbar and edit it to add whatever you want. The panel starts out as a vanilla panel only, not as a copy of the original, so will be missing all the extras.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22 I get this error: E: Package 'gnome-shell-extension-multi-monitors' has no installation candidate

Comment: @Raleigh L: Try the Gnome extension manager? See "https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/03/extension-manager-gnome-shell-new-icon" if not already installed. Then select extensions from there. Else see "https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337081/error-loading-multi-monitors-extension" for the manual approach (select correct version!).

Answer (score 1):

[Multi Monitors Add-On](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/) can do the trick.

As per [Installation from git](https://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on#installation-from-git):

```
git clone git://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on.git
cd multi-monitors-add-on
cp -r multi-monitors-add-on@spin83 ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
```

Restart the shell and then enable the extension.

Comment: Per the question, this is not applicable

Comment: "To be clear, I'm looking for something in a package manager or official channel, and not a custom script I can sideload."  -OP

Comment: @b264 - It depends on what you consider "official". This extension is listed in https://extensions.gnome.org/ ... I considered that "official". It was probably my misunderstanding.

Comment: Does not work for me. ```errno=Connection timed out```.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I would never consider cloning code with git as "officially supported".