# Error loading multi-monitors extension

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors

I've tried installing the extension by running `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-multi-monitors`, reloading the shell, then enabling it via gnome-tweaks. However the enable button is greyed out and it says "Error loading extension". I also tried installing it following the instructions on git https://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on but the results are the same.

The error seems to be "JS ERROR: Extension multi-monitors-add-on@spin83: TypeError: this._onButtonPress is undefined".

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with gnome version 3.36.7

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. The version of the extension I got from `app install` was for the wrong gnome version and so was the master branch of the git repo. I got it working by running `gnome-shell --version`, checking out the corresponding branch on the git repo and installing that.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the extension by "sudo sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-multi-monitors gnome-tweaks" I recommend:

1. Delete the file multi-monitors-add-on.pot from this location:
   ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
2. Install it through the git repository https://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on important select the branch according to your gnome version
3. Restart the gnome shell
   "killall -3 gnome-shell"